Return Column Based on Column Headers
I am trying to return a column based on column headers.  The data displayed is dynamic, based on a dropdown selection and the header names may thus be in different columns.
My data headers are in cells W6:AO6.  Here is how it looks:




W
X
Y
Z




6
Ticket number
Additional Details
Production Started
Production Completed


7
14392841
N/A
11/18/2024 07:59:17
11/18/2024 11:27:41


8
14339754
N/A
11/18/2024 09:59:24
11/18/2024 12:22:04


9
14327042
N/A
11/18/2024 10:53:19
11/18/2024 13:27:17


10
14275929
N/A
11/18/2024 07:40:41
11/18/2024 11:00:18


11
14318523
N/A
11/19/2024 06:15:34
11/19/2024 08:33:36



I have tried this formula in V7:
=QUERY(W7:AO,"SELECT "&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1, MATCH("Production Completed",W6:AO6,0), 4),1,""))

I get a #VALUE error saying:

Unable to parse query string for function query parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: D

In the sample, the expected result would be Z7:Z.
This formula works if my data starts in Column A, but because the MATCH part of the formula returns 4 which is Column D, I get an error.  In addition to various other attempts, I tried using OFFSET, but I could not get the formula to work.
Here is a sample sheet where the data or spreadsheet setup itself doesn't make much sense.
I have removed the actual data for privacy reasons:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1soFQnGsuIJLc0WuUtrSUgvR9JUgAN5Z8TvRoOBnw2r0/edit?gid=247110533#gid=247110533
Any suggestions on how to tweak this formula to get it to work?  Or is there a better formula to use?  Thanks for your help.

Can you provide a clear and concise expected result to help the community easily understand the problem statement


You may try:
=choosecols(W7:AO,xmatch("Production Completed",W6:AO6))

OR
=query(W7:AO,"select Col"&xmatch(Z6,W6:AO6))



Thank you.  Both return the correct results.  I have tweaked the query() formula to: =query(W7:AO,"select Col"&xmatch("Production Completed",W6:AO6))

Try this Alternative approach
Using INDEX() Returns the content of a cell, specified by row and column offset.
Formula used
=INDEX(W7:AO, , MATCH("Production Completed", W6:AO6, 0))

Sample output

Reference

INDEX


That also works.  Thank you.
